# how to add a war file and custom configuration to a wildfly docker image?

Tags: java, docker, wildfly, war

my war file runs on wildfly when I modify the standalone.xml adding the path to the file in a deployments section at the end of the file like the following:
    .
    .

```
</socket-binding-group>
  <deployments>
    <deployment name="mywar.war" runtime-name="mywar.war">
        <fs-exploded path="/local/path/exploded/mywar.war"/>
    </deployment>
  </deployments>
 </server>
```

How can I build a docker image like this?

I started with the following:

```
 FROM jboss/wildfly
 ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration
 ADD mywar.war mywar.war
```

where standalone.xml has the following:

```
  <deployment name="mywar.war" runtime-name="mywar.war">
        <fs-exploded path="/mywar.war"/>
  </deployment>
```

But when I run this docker image, wildfly complains:

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mywar.war (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix this? Where should my war go in the docker image? If I put it in deployment then wildfly complains that there is a duplicate resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it

Here is the entry I added to standalone.xml:

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="mywar.war" runtime-name="mywar.war">
        <fs-exploded path="/opt/jboss/wildfly/exploded/mywar.war"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

And here is the Dockerfile that worked for me:

```
 FROM jboss/wildfly
 ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration
 ADD build/libs/exploded /opt/jboss/wildfly/exploded
```